# How can I clip the background of the <body> element to its content box?

Tags: css, background, document-body

I have this style rule:

```
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 175%;
  margin: 0 15% 0;
  background-color: #d2dc9d;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

When I tested a page that made use of it, the `background-clip` property seemingly had no effect i.e. the background colour extended beyond the content box, over the margin and to the edge of the screen.

I went looking for an explanation in the specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-clip

> Note that the root element has a different background painting area,
>   and thus the `background-clip` property has no effect when specified on
>   it.

I also came across another related SO thread:

[Why does styling the background of the body element affect the entire screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225237/why-does-styling-the-background-of-the-body-element-affect-the-entire-screen)

> In CSS values are never propagated upward; that is, an element never
>   passes values up to its ancestors. There is an exception to the upward
>   propagation rule in HTML: background styles applied to the body
>   element can be passed to the html element, which is the document's
>   root element and therefore defines its canvas.

So is the case that the background colour I apply is being passed to from the `<body>` element to the root `<html>` element? And thus even though I can clip the background to the content box of`<body>`, the background colour passed to `<html>` will obscure the effect because it fills the canvas?

Whatever the reason, is there a way for me to *visibly* clip to the content box of `<body>`? Is my only option to insert a `<div>` between `<body>` and the body content and style that, if such a method would even work?

Comment: simply add a background color to html element, make it white and you will stop the propagation from body to html

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! That works and as a solution it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As Temani said earlier, adding background color to html is going to cancel out taking from body. If anyone wants more information about this topic, Kevin Powell has a nice, concise tutorial about that here: https://youtu.be/QUemJlZe7bo. Posting this just in case other people are struggling with it too and wonder why/how that works.