# Why when I set the body to position: relative, I get unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css, document-body

Any css masters know why this is happening? Or can explain it?  The p is being hoisted to behave like it is inside the div by adding position relative to body. I know `position:static` happens to the body by default, but when I set it to relative, the p tag behaves like it is nested inside the div tag. Anyone knows why this behavior is happening?

```css
body {
    background-color: purple;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;


}

div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;

}


p {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
        <div>
        <!-- it behaves like if it was here -->
        </div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: position:relative is not by default for any element. static is the default even for body

Comment: sorry that is what I meant. I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` is positioned at the bottom of its [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block **is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative'** or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
> ...
>
> If there is **no such ancestor**, the containing block is the **initial containing block**.

and the "initial containing block" is

> The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle called the initial containing block. For continuous media, it has the dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the page area for paged media.

So without `position:relative` on body, the element is placed at the bottom of the screen. with `position:relative` at the bottom of the body.

add border to the body element to see its boundary. The coloration is confusing you due to another feature which is [background propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5225237/8620333)

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border:2px solid green;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- it behaves like if it was here -->
  </div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok I did not know that. Correct once I remove the position: relative from the body, and move the P tag in between the div, the Hello World would stay in the same place as it is now. That is what was confusing me.