# Why does taking a percentage of body height result in 0

Tags: html, css

I was going through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) doc about containing blocks.
Note the [Example 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#example_2) here.

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p>This is a paragraph!</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

section {
  display: inline;
  background: lightgray;
}

p {
  width: 50%;     /* == half the body's width */
  height: 200px;  /* Note: a percentage would be 0 */
  background: cyan;
}
```

In the CSS inline comment, it states that a percentage would be 0.
Why is this the case?

My understanding has been that a block element's height would be the height of its content unless explicitly set. Can someone clarify why a percentage of the height would be zero and also, if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, percentage-based sizes are relative to the parent of the element. The parent must also have a fixed (read: non-percentage) size.

In this case, body has no defined height, and so you get this:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

section {
  display: inline;
  background: lightgray;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p></p>
  </section>
</body>
```

You can test this by giving `body` or `section` a fixed size and seeing the result:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
  height: 250px;
}

section {
  display: inline;
  background: lightgray;
}

p {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p></p>
  </section>
</body>
```

The cyan box now takes up 100% of the value of the `height` of `body`.

One of the workarounds that you will often see used for this scenario is that people will give the top-level container a size *relative to the viewport*. If we give `body`, say, *height: 50vh*, and then give `p` a `height` of 100%, even though viewport `height` is a scalar/percentage based unit, it will resolve as you would desire.

```css
body {
  background: beige;
  height: 50vh;
}

section {
  display: inline;
  background: lightgray;
}

p {
  width: 50%;  
  height: 100%; 
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p></p>
  </section>
</body>
```

However, because you have content inside of your `<p>` element, a percentage-based `height` would not resolve to *zero*. I believe the comment in the original example was made to illustrate the fact that a percentage-based `height` would not increase the height beyond the native size of the `<p>` and its contents, but could have been phrased slightly better to say something along these lines.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's question; they seem to be aware of the information you're providing in your answer.  Their question is specifically why `height: 200px` should be understood as _zero_ per the comment from MDN (unless I'm misunderstanding their intent).

Comment: Oh, I think you are actually correct. I have amended my answer to explain this part of their question as well. Thank you!

Comment: @loomy thank you for the detailed answer. However, can you tell me why the background color `beige` fills the whole screen in all the examples? Even when you have explicitly mentioned that the `height` value for `body` is `250px`, the background color extends to the whole screen. Note, I am viewing this on Firefox.

Comment: No problem! There is actually a very interesting explanation for this, and surprisingly, it is one of the rare exceptions where a child element communicates with its parent. [Check out this previously answered question for a good explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5225321/19747009)

Comment: Here is an answer to my question above: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225237/why-does-styling-the-background-of-the-body-element-affect-the-entire-screen). Update: I see that @loomy has already posted this answer.