# Why align to center in flexbox work so strange?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align to center very simple page. But can't understand why it's every time moving to left side. It should be at center.

```css
@media (width < 1600px) { 
  body {
     width: 80%; 
     background-color: #ee5011;
  }            
}
@media (width >= 1600px) { 
  body {
     width: 60%;
     background-color: #deaa19;
  }            
}
body {    
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
main {
   padding-left: 1em;
   padding-right: 1em;
   overflow-wrap: break-word; 
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <a href="/"><img alt="Logo"  height="70"></a>
</header>
<main>
   <h2>Step-by-step guide</h2>
   <div>
      <p>After thaeffffffffffffffff  s fsdf dsf sd fdsf sf sdf sdf sd sd fdsd s s s ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffваы ы аыв аыва ыва ыва ыв вы авы ыв авы ыв ыв fffffffffffffffffffffff eeeeeeeeeeeeeed allowing you to add and delete sections and subsections from the project.</p>
   </div>
</main>
```

[image]

Comment: It's because the body is 90% wide and the body itself is not aligned to the center, only the content inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the body is 90% wide and the body itself is not aligned to the center, only the content inside. if you want to center the body that is not 100% wide you can to use horizontal margin `auto`;

```css
@media (width < 1600px) { 
  body {
     width: 80%; 
     background-color: #ee5011;
  }            
}
@media (width >= 1600px) { 
  body {
     width: 60%;
     background-color: #deaa19;
  }            
}
body {    
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
main {
   padding-left: 1em;
   padding-right: 1em;
   overflow-wrap: break-word; 
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <a href="/"><img alt="Logo"  height="70"></a>
</header>
<main>
   <h2>Step-by-step guide</h2>
   <div>
      <p>After thaeffffffffffffffff  s fsdf dsf sd fdsf sf sdf sdf sd sd fdsd s s s ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffваы ы аыв аыва ыва ыва ыв вы авы ыв авы ыв ыв fffffffffffffffffffffff eeeeeeeeeeeeeed allowing you to add and delete sections and subsections from the project.</p>
   </div>
</main>
```

Comment: but why medua-queries stops to chagge color if to add `background-color: #118bee;` to `body` that outside media query?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov I think it's because of the cascade. Try adding media queries at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You've centred the *contents* of the body horizontally, but you also said:

> ```
> body {    
>    width: 90%;
>    margin: 0;
> ```

so the body is given a width of `90%` and a `0` left margin, so the body itself is left aligned.

To horizontally centre it, you would need the left and right margins to be `auto` (or `5%` less padding and borders).

Answer (score 0):

`<header>` and `<main>` are both aligned to centre of `<body>` their flexbox container. The body has a width of 90% hence why you are seeing the blank space.

You can verify this using inspect element tools in your browser, this isn't clear because the background colour is filling the entire page, for the reason described by Dribbel's answer here:

> [The body element is the root-element, and thus, as required by the CSS rules it loses its background style and the background style is applied to the containing canvas (the webpage area in the browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225237/why-does-styling-the-background-of-the-body-element-affect-the-entire-screen)

You likely want to apply your width to `<main>` instead of body to get your desired effect.